# How to have an image consistenly be side-by-side with another element?

Tags: html, css

I would like to do this -

I have multiple h2 headings in a code, and I want all of them to have an image of the Orioles Logo on both the left and right. Say I have 100 of them, and want to change them from the Orioles Logo to the Ravens Logo. Obviously, changing them would take ages.

To avoid this, I want to be able to use a css rule to do this:

Every time there is an H2 heading, you display a Ravens logo.
However, I can change that to an Orioles logo during the opening day of baseball season, then quickly change it back. (Totally not a Baltimore fanboi)

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked to the `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements in CSS? You can add content via them...

Comment: have you tried something ? If you have a Sample code, please post

Answer (score 1):

Using the CSS's pseudo-elements :before and :after you can add images before and after an element.

[Here is a working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/psrbw8cw/)

```
h2:not(.current):before {
  content: " ";
  background-image: url(.....);
}

h2.current:before {
  content: " ";
  background-image: url(.....);
}
```